# How to Create New Levels at Runtime

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on a maze game. I have 3 levels for now but hereafter I want to make and save new levels at runtime (in game). So is there any way to create new scenes and save them as "levels" to load them later with Application.LoadLevel("createdScene") in android?

Comment: I´m sure there is more than one way.

Comment: I think perhaps one approach you could consider is to have an empty level. Save a text file with a list of object names used and their positions, then at runtime simply parse that file and create your maze by instantiating the given objects. This option gives you a lot of room to grow, such as sharing maze designs with others, easily uploading them online somewhere, etc.

Comment: Thank you Steven. This is a good idea and I will use this way if I cannot find any way to create 'new' scenes for each level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can save the data of all objects in a XML, and save or read the info from there. Exemple

```
<Maze id="1" Level="1">
  <item id="1" posx="0" posy="1" image="image.png"/>
  <item id="2" posx="0" posy="4" image="image2.png"/>
  <item id="3" posx="2" posy="1" image="image3.png"/>
  <item id="4" posx="0" posy="6" image="image4.png"/>
</Maze>

<Maze id="2" Level="2">
  <item id="1" posx="0" posy="1" image="image.png"/>
  <item id="2" posx="0" posy="4" image="image2.png"/>
  <item id="3" posx="2" posy="1" image="image3.png"/>
  <item id="4" posx="0" posy="6" image="image4.png"/>
</Maze>
```

using this you can create all your maze in one level.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best way to do it is to make one scene as a scaffold/template for your levels and then Instantiate prefabs or load data into your gameobjects as the new level loads.

Comment: Thanks Dawid. As I said to Steven this is a good alternative way. Even if it's not what exactly I wanted